# Trying to get the "P" and "Q" in two nodes of a TikZ diagram typeset on the same baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf

The "Q" is clearly typeset too far from the gray line segment, and it is not drawn on the same baseline as the "P." The reason that I have a node named `(auxiliary node for Q)` is so that the tail of the "Q" will be ignored in the placement of the letter. (The "O" in this node should be obscured by the "Q" - except for its tail - in the succeeding node command.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}





\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}



%Part of two ellipses and a parabola are drawn.
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
\path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw (3,0) arc (180:90: 2 and 1);
\draw (3,0) arc (180:252: 2 and 1);
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
\path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$F$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=0mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
\path node[anchor=south west] at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75){$P$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between (3,0) and its label Q.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3,0) -- ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$);
\path node[anchor=south east] (auxiliary node for Q) at ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$){$O$};
\path node[anchor=north west] at (auxiliary node for Q.north west){$Q$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try to set `text depth=0pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** After follow-up question

Aligning the node `Q` with  node `P` baseline using `anchor=base`  and `baseline={P.base}` , and making **P** and **Q** aligned with the gray lines.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}         
            %Part of two ellipses and a parabola are drawn.
            \draw (0,0) arc (0:90: 2 and 1);
            \draw (0,0) arc (0:-72: 2 and 1);
            \path node[anchor=east] at ({-2+sqrt(31)/8},-15/16){$E$};
        
            \draw (3,0) arc (180:90: 2 and 1);
            \draw (3,0) arc (180:252: 2 and 1);

            \draw[domain=-1:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-1/9*\x*\x + 1/3*\x});
            \path node[anchor=south west, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-1mm] at (3.75,-5/16){$F$};
            
            % put on top <<<<<<<
            \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
            
            %A "pin" is drawn between (0,0) and its label.
            \draw[gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=0mm] (0,0) -- ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75);
            %A "pin" is drawn between (3,0) and its label           
            \draw[gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3,0) -- ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$);
            
            \node(P)[anchor=south west, inner sep =0] at ({(atan(1/3)+90)/2}:0.75 ){$P$};
            \node(Q)[anchor=base, baseline={P.base}, inner sep =0] at ($(3,0) +({(atan(-1/3)+180+90)/2}:0.75)$) {$Q$};          

        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{center}        
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know that `baseline` was an option. That is helpful.

Comment: Of course, I want the "P" and the "Q" to be aligned with the gray lines. I get an error using `anchor=base south west` for positioning "P," and I get an error using  `anchor=base south east` for positioning "Q."

Comment: @user143462 Please see the updated answer.

Comment: This version is what I want. Thanks!